# Can I specify how to handle errors in the async javascript library?

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, async.js

I'm trying to sanitize inputs for an asynchronous function. Specifically, given a list of credentials for an API, I'm trying to filter out which ones are invalid by sending a test request to the API and examining the result for each one.

The problem I'm facing is this: I would like to collect the invalid keys into a single list. I would normally use the `async` library to execute the requests in sequence, using the `series` function. But, from the documentation:

> If any functions in the series pass an error to its callback, no more functions are run, and `callback` is immediately called with the value of the error.

This isn't the desired behavior: I want to collect the errors in place of the responses (or both of them). Is this possible, using this library, without changing the way I'm interacting with the API?

Comment: Instead of passing an error directly into the callback, what about passing an error key in the success callback? Though that would probably go against what this library is for.

Comment: @BenFortune That changes the way I'm interacting with the API; I don't want to change the way I'm accessing everything and sending responses back just for this small piece of the application.

Comment: What about just adding them to an array outside the `async.series` function scope? You can then do what you like when the series has finished in the final callback.

Comment: @BenFortune That doesn't work asynchronously, but I actually did find a solution -- I'll post it in a sec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to this problem ended up being sort of hacky, but it works fine. I had a list of `credentials` and an async function `apiCall`, which looked like this:

```
var apiCall = function(arg, callback){
    ...
}
```

and the solution was to use `mapSeries` from `async`, but flip the callback arguments, like this:

```
async.mapSeries(credentials, function(creds, callback){
    apiCall(creds, function(err, res){
      callback(null, err);
    });
  }, 
function(nil, errors){
    console.log(_.compact(errors));
});
```

where `_.compact` removes falsy elements from the array, getting rid of the `null`s that non-error responses returned. This got me exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: What happens to the `data`? What does `res` mean, it never will contain an error?

Comment: @Bergi `res` is always `null` (I'm setting it in `callback`). In my particular case, I don't care at all about what the response is, only if I'm getting an error back. Setting `res` to `null` ensures that `async` will never detect what they would consider an "error," but instead propagate the actual errors as what they would consider a valid response.

Comment: Yeah, I understand how it works, but the naming - `res`(ult/ponse) - might suggest that it contains the data. You might make it more clear that you discard the `data`.